# Rails first_or_initialize not updating record

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sql-update, persistence

I'm using the code below to either create a new record or update an existing one. Create is working, update is not.

```
Signup.find_or_initialize_by(email: "text@example.com") do |signup|
  signup.name = "John Doe"
  signup.save
end
#Signup.find(email: "test@example.com").name = nil
```

Not sure why since `save` also updates records. FWIW, I tried a different syntax below which did work, not sure the difference, but I'd like to keep the `find_or_initialize` block version.

```
signup = Signup.find_or_initialize_by(email: "text@example.com")
signup.name = "John Doe"
signup.save
#Signup.find(email: "test@example.com").name = "John Doe"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block is only called if no matching row is found in the database: your first version will never modify an already existing row with requested email address.

If that's what you want to do, your second example is the way to go.